# Evaluate trained and loaded CNN keras model problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new in the deep neuron network world. I tried to train my one model using the TensorFlow Keras toolkit.

I managed to train a model using the `fit` function. The accuracy, for 50 epochs, was good - around 96% and the model predicts well with new data. The problem is when I try to evaluate the loaded model the results are like the model wasn't trained at all (accuracy around 50%).

I prepare the small test. I evaluate the model after a `fit`. Then I save the model, load it, and evaluate it once again. The results are so different. I thought that maybe weights aren't loaded properly, but the documentation suggests that save and load functions operate on the whole model. Here is my code:

```
CNNmodelHistory = model.fit(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=test_data, steps_per_epoch=train_data.samples // batch_size,
                            epochs=echos)


scores = model.evaluate(test_data, verbose=0)
print(f'Test loss: {scores[0]} / Test accuracy: {scores[1]}')

# save the model to disk
model.save('gender_detection.modelTest')

modelLoaded = keras.models.load_model('gender_detection.modelTest')
scores = modelLoaded.evaluate(test_data, verbose=0)
print(f'Test loss: {scores[0]} / Test accuracy: {scores[1]}')
```

And here are the results:
[image]

Do you have any tips on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does trying `tf.keras.models.load_model` instead of `keras.models.load_model` have any effect?

Comment: No, the same problem.